Can you make a palisade/wall from sharpened palm tree trunks?
I have a setting where some shipwreck survivors need to protect themselves from monsters attacking the place they landed. They need to go further in-land to get building wood to repair the ship, but I'd like them to build some palisade in the meantime. Would it make sense they can build it from palm trees, but for ship repair they need wood?

Civil war generals in Charleston would line forts with palm tree trunks as they were great for absorbing cannon fire.

Please edit the question to show what is the perceived problem with palm tree trunks. (And the trunks of palm trees are made of wood. What do you think they are made of?) P.S. In the age of sails and wooden ships the ships did carry spare spars and planks, because they might need repairs at sea, or on the Skeleton Coast, or some other place where big trees are hard to come by.

Good point on specifying the type of palisade, as I learned from searching for "palm palisade". Palms are not wood though, in a sense that would let them be used for planks etc. I did think of the ship carrying its own wood for some repair, but the thing was they decided to build a palisade rather than repair ship to live long enough to be able to repair it later. It's pretty significant decision for the whole plot so I wanted to make sure palms were not very suitable for palisade-like structures.

Coconut timber.

You also need to be more specific about the type of 'monster' they're threatened by. Particularity their size, strength climbing ability etc nor have you defined the number of crew available to build the stockade.

Could you edit to greatly clarify what the problem is that you're facing as it's very unclear at present what worldbuilding problem is being presented here.

Given the history of many kinds of construction in palm timber, including colonial fortifications I can't help but feel that zero research was done on this issue before you asked the question.

Sure, as a temporary palisade palms would be fine. They're not the hardest wood and they'll deteriorate comparatively quickly but they'll work.
You can use palm wood as building material, but, unless processed properly it's very susceptible to moisture and will absorb water and rot if given half a chance. But it will last a while, long enough for your purpose anyway.

Your second paragraph also explains why, if they had a choice, they'd look for other kinds of wood to repair their ships.

This may seem obvious but the crew might already have a ready made stockade in the form of the ship they arrived on. If it's beached on the island in such a way that the crew can (1) actually access it easily enough to make the needed repairs and (2) The damage is limited enough that they only have to make 'repairs' (and not rebuild it from scratch)?
Why not just hole up on board the vessel?

I thought the access to the ship would be rather easy, as the monsters swim quite well. The issue they faced was that on ship they couldn't know when and where from the attack would come. On land there was only one way to enter the short beach, as most of the shore is just cliffs. Decision to fortify farther but in an easier to defend position would be logical IMO.

The point being NONE of what you've just said is defined in your original question. If the 'monsters' can (& have to) swim to the ship? How at the same time can your hero's be expected to repair it?' Think about it.  It's basically physically impossible to repair a ship that's grounded so far off shore that the crew has to swim out to reach it! Explain how that works. Sure, they can 'Swiss family Robertson' (look it up) & strip the vessel for parts. But what they can't do is repair it! You need to (a) define your monsters capabilities precisely and (b) explain how/what the crew hopes to do.
